# Automatic Search and Replace in Google Sheets with a script

Tags: google-apps-script, text, google-sheets, find-replace

I do not typically work with scripts, but I am fairly confident with formulas:

I have a list of student names in a set of cells.
For example:

In cell AF1, it says:
Tommy Jones
Marta Lewis
James, Jessica
Jennifer Annis
Bones, Raymond

In cell AF2, it says:
Jessica James
Bones, Raymond
Lewis, Marta
Davidson, Joanna
Field, Jennifer

And so forth for more than 150 cells in that column.

All of the affected cells are in column AF (they are created from a concatenated list - so they are the result of a different formula).

I need to make sure that they are all Last name, First name.

**I have been trying to copy/paste from other people's scripts that seemed useful, but I've gotten frustrated and deleted all of them:**

I have tried to create a long script that included:

var to_replace = "Jonathan Adkins";
var replace_with = "Adkins, Jonathan";

var to_replace = "Joshua Adkins";
var replace_with = "Adkins, Joshua";
(all 400 names)

and one that included:
replaceinsheet(sheet,'Jonathan Adkins','Adkins, Jonathan');
replaceinsheet(sheet,'Joshua Adkins','Adkins, Joshua');
(all 400 names)

and one that listed them this way:
replaceInSheet(values, 'Jonathan Adkins', 'Adkins, Jonathan');

and I've tried to create additional columns beside my concatenated column that has the names and using this formula:
creating a script to define =arrayreplace and then using this formula.
=arrayreplace(AF1,AI2:AI,AJ2:AJ)

I'm stuck.  Can someone please help?

I've created a sample sheet to hopefully show what I'm talking about:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gyAdIxletLuJzubVkOmgYmlgt5iw0Ezul1kS4uLbBu8/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: The inbuilt find/replace would require me to do it 380+ times, and if I add to it later, I'd have to do them all again.
I would love to do it with formulas but I don't know how to incorporate all 380 possible changes when the text is not the entire cell.  .

Comment: What's difference between a lastname and a firstname?  I used to deliver newspaper to a lady named George George.

Comment: @Eliza  Explained how you would do it

Answer (score 1):

#### Inbuilt Find and Replace:

- Select the range you want to change: Sheet1!A1:L10
- Edit >Find and replace
- Find:

  ```
  (\w+),?\s+([A-z]+)
  ```
- Replace:

  ```
  $2, $1
  ```
- Checkmark: Use regular expressions
- Click Replace All

#### Formula:

Alternatively, You could use,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(L2:L10,"(\w+),?\s+(\w+)","$2, $1"))
```

#### Explanations:

- `\w`: A letter (`\w`ord)
- `,`: literal `,`
- `\s`: A `s`pace
- `+`: one or more of the previous matched character
- `?`: one or zero of  the previous matched character
- `()`: capture group
- `$`: Replacement of the numbered capture group

Comment: @Eliza Thank you!  However, that seems to switch the names regardless if they are wrong or not.  Some of the names are already Last, First and some are First Last.  I need to make the ones that First Last into Last, First.
Also, I am stuck with a sheet that has multiple names in one cell as a list.  The end list must be in that format too.

I was also hoping to use this same script/formula to handle when students have an alternative name:   Michael Bacon --> Mike Bacon --> Bacon, Mike (though I can do that in multiple steps). 

Thank you so much for working on this for me!

Comment: @Eliza *seems to switch the names regardless if they are wrong or not. Some of the names are already Last, First and some are First Last.* What's the difference? The comma? How would the computer know which names are already in Last, First? *First. Also, I am stuck with a sheet that has multiple names in one cell as a list. The end list must be in that format too.* Both ye formula and  the inbuilt fr doesn't change  the format.

Comment: Yes, the difference is the comma.  

In one cell, we'd have:
Jessica James
Jones, Tommy

Jessica is the given name.  James is the surname.
Tommy is the given name.  Jones is the surname.

I would need that cell to say:
James, Jessica
Jones, Tommy

Even if in another cell, it already was correct.

Comment: Great!  However, that seems to only fix the first occurrence in each cell - is there any way to ensure it does all occurrences in each cell?

Comment: @Eliza It replaces all occurrences for me. Make sure you disable all other settings like Match entire cell in  find-replace.